# Why this isn't a distribution function?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $F:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function defined by $F(x,y)=1-\exp(-x-y)$ if $x\geq 0$ and $y\geq 0$, and $F(x,y)=0$ otherwise. How do I prove that $F$ is not the distribution of a random vector $(X,Y)$?

Comment: The mixed partial derivative $\frac {\partial^2}{\partial x \partial y}F(x,y)$ exists but is negative.

Comment: You get $F(0,\infty)=1$ suggesting $\mathbb P(X \le 0)$.  Similarly $F(\infty,0)=1$ suggesting $\mathbb P(Y \le 0)=1$, but these two are inconsistent with $F(0,0)=0$

Comment: @Henry could you expand on why they are inconsistent with $F(0,0)=0$?

Comment: Because of the literal definition of distribution function.

Comment: Benja: If "$X\le 0$" with probability $1$ and "$Y\le 0$" with probability $1$ then you would have "$X\le 0$ and $Y\le 0$" with probability $1$ not $0$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are asking if $F$ is the probability distribution function of a pair 
 $U,V$ of random variables so that for all $x,y$ we have $P(U\le x \text{ and } V\le y)=F(x,y)$, the answer is "no".  Because such functions must assign non-negative values to events of form $[x<U\le x+h\text{ and } y<V\le y+k]$, that is, the inequality $F(x+h,y+k)-F(x+h,y)-F(x,y+k)+F(x,y)\ge0$ must be satisfied by all real $x,y$ and all non-negative $h,k$.

Your $F$ does not. Taking $F(x,y)=1-\exp(-x-y)$, the requirement that 
$$ (1-e^{-(x+h)-(y+k)}) + (1-e^{-x-y}) - (1-e^{-(x+h)-y}) - (1-e^{-x-(y+k)})\ge0$$ turns into 
$$ e^{-x-y}\left(e^{-h}+e^{-k}-e^{-h-k}-1\right)\ge0$$
which in turn means $-(1-e^{-h})(1-e^{-k})\ge0$, which does not hold for *any* $x,y,k,h\ge0$.

In a comment, Henry posted an example that boils down to $h=k=\infty$, and I posted a comment that comes down to picking $h,k$ infinitesimally small.

Comment: This might be more persuasive with an explicit example of $x,y,h,k$

Comment: @Henry Happier?

Comment: Maybe, but something like $x=y=0, h=k=1$ might have worked too